# Will https also protect the url address after the domain name?

Tags: security, https, privacy

For example, right now the address is `https://superuser.com/questions/ask`, so will the "questions/ask" part be leaked?

Other case: `https://superuser.com/posts/1385520/edit`

Will a hacker know that I'm editing this question?

Comment: Define "hacker". Where are they, what access do they have to your computer &/or router?

Comment: Related [Are HTTPS URLs encrypted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/499591/1699210)

Comment: It is highly depend on what kind of access the third party has. If he has comprised your computer or your target it is going to be way different than just someone seeing your network traffic pass by. HTTPS have a look at [With HTTPS, are the URL and the request headers protected as the request body is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858102/with-https-are-the-url-and-the-request-headers-protected-as-the-request-body-is)

Answer (score -1):

HTTPS-URLs are themselves not encrypted, so an attacker CAN see where you are. He CAN'T see what you are sending or receiving though.